# MacOS with multiple monitors: how to open windows always on the screen where the mouse is?

Tags: macos, mac

How can you configure MacOS to always open new windows (for any app) on the **same** screen where the mouse pointer is?

Using multiple monitors on Mac OSX, new windows get opened on a different monitor from where the mouse pointer is. e.g. iTerm2, Finder, ... Pretty annoying to have to search for new windows.

Is there a configuration or tool to make OSX always place new windows of any application on the same screen where the mouse pointer is? preferrably under the mouse pointer.

Comment: Focus doesn’t follow the mouse until a window is selected.  See this answer for a possible solution (also possible dupe): https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/87655/119271. Another possible dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5/119271. And another: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/245364/119271

Comment: Have you tried any of the above?  What were the results?

Comment: @Allan that is not what I am asking - I want the focus to be on the window without explicitly selecting (clicking) the window - the same way as this works on UNIX/LINUX

Comment: That’s not a Unix/Linux (macOS is a certified Unix BTW) convention, that feature belongs to X-Windows (Xorg).  Aqua, the macOS GUI, doesn’t support this.  It doesn’t do “focus on hover”

Comment: @Allan while X-windows has that feature, previous Mac OSX window managers have included these features, e.g.CodeTek Desktop Pro - that was not for X windows, but the regular Mac UI